# in python using amazon bottlenose api, I have NameError

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, bottlenose

why NameError: name 'amazon' is not defined??

it is no plablem, if it is no in function.

but if in amazon_api() function,
 it is error 'name 'amazon' is not defined'.

how can i use amazon_api() function without Error ??

```
import bottlenose
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def item_search(keywords, search_index="Toys", item_page= 1):
    response = amazon.ItemSearch(SearchIndex=search_index, Keywords=keywords, ItemPage=item_page, ResponseGroup="Large")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('item')

def item_Lookup(item_id):
    response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId= item_id,  ResponseGroup="Images")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('largeimage')

def amazon_api():
    api_id = 'your api_id'
    api_key = 'your api_key'
    tag_id = 'your tag_id'

    amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(api_id,api_key,tag_id)    
    item = item_search('nike', search_index="All", item_page= 1)
    asin = item.find('asin').text

    print(asin)
    img = item_Lookup(asin)
    print(img)

amazon_api()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\bottlenose.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       amazon_api()   File "C:\Python34\bottlenose.py", line 21, in amazon_api
>       item = item_search('nike', search_index="All", item_page= 1)   File "C:\Python34\bottlenose.py", line 6, in item_search
>       response = amazon.ItemSearch(SearchIndex=search_index, Keywords=keywords, ItemPage=item_page, ResponseGroup="Large")
>   NameError: name 'amazon' is not defined

Comment: `amazon` is defined only in local scope of `amazon_api()`. It i snot accessible in local scopes of other functions.

Comment: really? omg !! im very sad